# how to allow users to select the photos in the unity android game?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

In my game i want allow users to select some **Photos**. So,these made as **Textures**      for **GameObjects** in Unity3D android game. 
I tried publishing it  through the *Google andriod project* and then with 
eclipse tool.
but i didn't find anything about making textures or images and then
pass it to the game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing some searching, it looks like the answer to this question is "write a native plugin". Fortunately, [somebody has already done that](http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/1139517/view.html) for you.

You will want to replace the provided SetImage function with some code of your own, instead of setting image.texture, you will want to GetComponent the renderer of the object whose texture you want to set, get the material of that Renderer, and then set its mainTexture to your new photo-texture.

Comment: Thanks Bro. I downloaded **Android Unified API** Plugin from the Asset Store that worked perfectly.